# Sort with two key value

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to convert a code, and I ran into this line, and I'm not sure what it does. I know I can sort using a key like `a:a*a`, but how does it handle two keys?

this is the line I am trying to convert (to C#, if it matters):

```
 arr.sort(lambda a,b:a-b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False)
>
> Sort the items of the list in place (the arguments can be used for sort customization, see sorted() for their explanation).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable
>   elements) which should return a negative, zero or positive number
>   depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than,
>   equal to, or larger than the second argument: cmp=lambda x,y:
>   cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). The default value is None.

`lambda a,b` is for defining an anonymous function in Python.

So this is the same as

```
def f(a,b):
    return a-b

arr.sort(f)
```

Which naturally returns `> 0` if `a > b` and `0` if `a==b`.

As @MartijnPieters points out, this should be plain "natural" sorting and, were we in the absence of operator overloading (e.g. plain integers), it would be the same as `sort()` with no arguments.

Comment: Erm, sorry, not reversed but forward sorting. The `lambda` can be removed altogether and the sort order would still be the same, unless the values sorted are custom objects with different behaviour when compared with `<` vs. subtraction.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You are not going insane, I have modified my answer since I had mistakenly typed a `>` instead of a `<` (bear with me, it's a Saturday :).

Comment: That was indeed what threw me, I should have paid more attention though.

Comment: I actually noticed the mistake thanks to your comment. "Sure, right, it's just `reversed`, I'll edit this into my answer". Three seconds later: "no, wait." I was/am reluctant to into the actual meaning of the `lambda` because I have no idea of what the OP's manipulating and it could very well be that they have some kind of weird behaviour (or the guy who wrote the original code got paid by number of code lines)

Comment: This is one of the reasons `cmp` support went the way of the Dodo in Python 3; too damn confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the array **arr** by passing the sorting comparison function as a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html).

Lambdas are small locally defined functions, witch are also available in C#.

Finally, the call sorts the array based on the difference of variable.